# how to inset a new object in CoreDta and reflect the change in the relationship between two entities?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

in my IOS10, swift 3, xcode8 application, I have Movie in coreData.

```
Movie: {id:Int32, name:String, genre: [ {Genre} ]  }   
Genre: {id:Int32, name:String}
```

the way I did it, is by creating a movie entity, and a genre entity, and set up many-to-many relationship between them...
is this correct ? cause one movie can have many genres, like action, comedy
and a genre, like romantic, can be associated with many movies.

my second question is, when I am saving a new movie to CoreData, How will the Genre entity know what happened, is there like a CoreData Feature that will do that automatically? or I should add a movie to the genre Set, and add a genre set for movie ?
my end goal is to be able to search for movies by titles, or by genre.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly basic, so I would recommend researching it: [CoreData Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

But a basic rundown is when you create a many<->many relationship CoreData creates a connections table between the two models. The way coreData works is with managed objects, meaning every time you try and access an attribute of an NSManagedObject it will be the value in the saved database.

When you add something to a many-many relationship, the connections table will create the connection, and when access it from either model, the results will be based on that connections table.

TLDR, in CoreData if you have a relationship between two models, you only need to add the connection to one of the models.

Comment: maybe I didn't format my question in the correct way... I am reading data from Json file, and in my genre entity I have a fixed number of genre with unique id (already saved in coreData), so when I'm reading from the json file, and creating a new movie, I want to make sure that the movie is being linked to the already existing genre in my table, not create a new genre entry. the apple documentation present all the possible functions, but don't advise on what to use when. that's why I thought I would find a tailored answer to my specific question. NYW thank you for your response.

Comment: Simply get the genre to which you want to add the movie, and add the move to the genre.